# opencv 3.0 and cv-bridge

Tags: cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently using OpenCv 3.0. And now I would like to use it with ROS (as Ros still has OpenCv 2.4 ). I need to use cv_bridge in my work. However, because cv_bridge is linked with open cv libraries of openCV 2.4 (which I must hide from ROS system inorder to use opencv3.0) I tried to compile it with 3.0 libraries, but without any success.
There are a lot of changes made on transitioning from 2.4 to 3.0 including lots of variable names.

Has anyone tried to do so with any sucess? I would appreciate any information on how to proceed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133416/opencv-3.0-and-cv-bridge/) by [espee](https://answers.ros.org/users/6531/espee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2014-02-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think it should be too hard to fix those errors right? Most errors are probably things like

```
CV_RGB2GRAY
```

To

```
cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY
```

cv_bridge isn't that big so I'd try to fix those errors (and perhaps do a pull request when you are done)

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2014-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0